# How to change default color of Chakra Theme?

Tags: reactjs, colors, themes, chakra-ui

I'm customizing the colors of my project using Chakra UI, but I came across a situation that I couldn't find in the project's documentation.

Well, I used extendTheme to change the green colors.

```js
const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
    green: {
      50: "#ecfdf5",
      100: "#d1fae5",
      200: "#a7f3d0",
      300: "#6ee7b7",
      400: "#34d399",
      500: "#10b981",
      600: "#059669",
      700: "#047857",
      800: "#065f46",
      900: "#064e3b",
    },
  },
});
```

This in itself is working. When I use it in a component, for example:

```
<Box bg="green.400" />
```

The problem arises when I try to use just the name green. It uses the default green from CSS and not one of the 50-900 shades of green that I defined. I don't know how I can define a color to be the default.

Comment: Honestly i think you're just one word away... the color may be "green 400"
but the object in the theme is `colors.green.400`. So my suggestion is just add "colors" at the beginning. 

My code looks like this: 
```colors: {
    brand: {
      primary: {
        "50": "#e0f3ee",
        "100": "#b4e2d3",
        ...      
    },
        ...more colors...```
and usage: 
    const bg_color = useColorModeValue(
        "colors.brand.primary.50",
        "colors.brand.primary.100"
      );

    <Box bgColor={bg_color} />

Answer (score 1):

The key word that helped me find the solution was `semanticTokens`.

With this configuration, I managed to define a token for the `green` color.

```js
const theme = extendTheme({
      semanticTokens: {
        colors: {
          green: "green.500",
        },
      },
      colors: {
        green: {
          50: "#ecfdf5",
          100: "#d1fae5",
          200: "#a7f3d0",
          300: "#6ee7b7",
          400: "#34d399",
          500: "#10b981",
          600: "#059669",
          700: "#047857",
          800: "#065f46",
          900: "#064e3b",
        },
      },
    });
```

More information can be found at:

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/semantic-tokens

In the documentation, they use terms like `success`, `danger`, `error`, etc. But color names can also be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, but 'green' itself doesn't have much of a semantic meaning.  Compared to their example of 'success'.

The better way to approach this at the component level is to use a component theme

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/component-style#consuming-style-config

So you create a component, say, Card, and build a theme up for the Card component, giving it a `bgColor` of `green.500` or whatever.

```
const Card = defineStyleConfig({
  baseStyle: {
    bgColor: 'green.500'
  }
})
```

then after adding `Card` to your theme, do -

```
function Card(props) {
  const styles = useStyleConfig('Card')

  return <Box __css={styles} {...props} />
}
```

Then everywhere you will just render your `<Card>...</Card>` component.

For complex components, you can use a multi-style config - https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/component-style#styling-multipart-components whereby you define each of the 'parts' of your component, and give each part its own theme.